# Using class types in switch

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, c++11

I'm trying to `switch` on a custom type. The Standard says

> The condition shall be of integral type, enumeration type, or of a
>   class type for which a single non-explicit conversion function to
>   integral or enumeration type exists (12.3). If the condition is of
>   class type, the condition is converted by calling that conversion
>   function, and the result of the conversion is used in place of the
>   original condition for the remainder of this section. Integral
>   promotions are performed.

This suggests that a type which has one implicit conversion function to an `enum` type should be a valid `switch` expression. But when I'm trying to use this wording, Visual Studio gives an error about the switch expression being non-integral. Is VS just non-compliant in this area?

The definition of the class type is

```
    struct Token {
        Token()
            : line(0)
            , columnbegin(0)
            , columnend(0) {}
        Token(const Codepoint& cp) {
            *this = cp;
        }
        template<typename Iterator> Token(Iterator begin, Iterator end) {
            columnend = 0;
            columnbegin = 0;
            line = 0;
            while(begin != end) {
                *this += *begin;
                begin++;
            }
        }
        operator TokenType() {
            return type;
        }
        Token& operator+=(const Codepoint& cp) {
            if (cp.column >= columnend)
                columnend = cp.column;
            if (columnbegin == 0)
                columnbegin = cp.column;
            Codepoints += cp.character;
            if (line == 0)
                line = cp.line;
            return *this;
        }
        Token& operator=(const Codepoint& cp) {
            line = cp.line;
            columnbegin = cp.column;
            columnend = cp.column;
            Codepoints = cp.character;
            return *this;
        }

        int line;
        int columnbegin;
        int columnend;
        TokenType type;
        string Codepoints;
    };
```

with `switch(*begin)` as the erroring line where `begin` is a `vector<Token>::iterator`.

Edit:

Please, READ THE QUESTION. You want to see my code? How about the *bleedingly obvious that I stated in the line right above this one*? Maybe I should put it in size fifty letters in bold and italics.

```
std::vector<Token>::iterator begin = vector.begin();
switch(*begin) {
case TokenType::stuff:
}
```

Comment: OOoh interesting... can you post some pseudo-code?

Comment: @AhmedMasud it's pretty clear... you just use objects who can be converted to integral types.

Comment: It's working for me on GCC. Post some code?

Comment: @SethCarnegie hehe i just didn't want to "create" it myself, i have a bunch of compilers that i can run it through and see which ones would comply ... Was just being lazy about it... I really shouldn't have said pseudo-code, i meant to say skeleton test code tee hee

Comment: Which standard are you referring to? It is strange that the standard says it will allow switching on a C++ class, since that would be a way to "work around" polymorphism.

Comment: It doesn't directly allow you to `switch` on class types, but on objects of class types that provide a non-explicit conversion operator like described.

Comment: You misread. You don't switch on the class, but on an integral or enumeration type instance that the class instance can be converted too implicitly.

Comment: Why would you post lots of irrelevant code and no relevant code? Something like http://ideone.com/6K2FC which compiles fine with VC++ 2005 (don't have a newer one). - And WTF is it with upvoting such a poorly presented question?!

Comment: Similar code [compiles fine in g++](http://www.ideone.com/xrDOU).

Comment: ¤ As I'm writing this you haven't shown the code that fails. But most probably you're class instances as `switch` labels (the switch expression causes a jump to one of the labels, in general). Labels cannot be class instances, they have to be integral. Cheers & hth.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a bug in VC. GCC [4.5](http://ideone.com/U2mb6) and 4.7 compile this, no problems:

```
enum class e { roy, gee, biv };

struct s { operator e() { return e::gee; } };

void f() {
    switch ( s() ) {
        case e::roy: case e::biv: case e::gee: break;
    }
}
```

Does this more minimal testcase make VC happy as well?