# Resolving ambiguous user-defined-conversion where ambiguity is hidden

Tags: c++

The following code creates a Base class wrapper for an integer. It provides a method value() to get and set its value as well as a user-defined-conversion and an assignment operator for convenience.

The derived class is a template (intended to be used with enums) which inherits the Base class wrapper which hides the Base class' value(), user-defined-conversion and assignment operator and replaces them with versions that work specifically with the provided template parameter (an enum).

```
class Base
{
public:
    Base( int e ) : e_(e) {}

    inline const int& value() const { return e_; }
    inline void value( int e ) { e_ = e; }

    inline operator const int& () const { return value(); }
    inline Base& operator= ( int e ) { value( e ); return *this; }

protected:
    int e_;
};

template< typename E >
class Enum : public Base
{
    using Base::value;
    using Base::operator const int&;
    using Base::operator=;
public:
    Enum( E e ) : Base( e ) {}

    inline E value() const { return static_cast<E>( Base::value() ); }
    inline void value( E e ) { Base::value( e ); }

    inline operator E () const { return static_cast<E>( Base::value() ); }
    inline Enum<E>& operator= ( E e ) { Base::value( e ); return *this; }
};

enum foo_t {
    FOO_A,
    FOO_B,
    FOO_C
};
typedef Enum<foo_t> Foo;
```

Now let's invoke this code like so:

```
Foo e( FOO_A );

e = FOO_B; // Ok!
foo_t b = e; // Ok!

// Why is this not ok?
if ( e ) {
    printf("error C2451!");
}
if ( e.value() ) { // Ok!
    e = FOO_C;
}

// Why is this not ok?
switch ( e ) {
default:
    printf("error C2450!");
}
switch ( e.value() ) { // Ok!
default:
    e = FOO_A;
}
```

Why do the if and switch statements fail to compile (`Ambiguous user-defined-conversion`) when I've explicitly hidden the base class' user-defined-conversion (and should not be accessible for the if and switch statements). The equally ambiguous `e.value()` function does not suffer from this problem.

```
1>test.cpp(60): error C2451: conditional expression of type 'Foo' is illegal
1>          Ambiguous user-defined-conversion
1>test.cpp(69): error C2450: switch expression of type 'Foo' is illegal
1>          Ambiguous user-defined-conversion
```

Comment: There's no such thing as "explicit hiding". Access control and name lookup are completely separate, unrelated concepts.

Comment: Also, please use ISO standard C++, which has been around since 1998. You appear to be using some pre-standard dialect.

Comment: I found [this resource](http://accu.org/index.php/journals/268) mentioning name lookup and access control. From this I infer that in this case, hiding (& making private) a base class member does not help resolving ambiguity as 'access control' is not yet invoked when the ambiguity occurs, is this correct?

Comment: @KerrekSB I assume that with your comment referencing the lack of ISO standard C++ you are referring to the fact that the (equally ambiguous) `e.value()` compiled successfully (when it shouldn't)?

Comment: @MicroCode I think he was referring to your use of deprecated access declarations in the derived class. You should be using `using` statements instead.

Comment: @MicroCode Ignore my comment, I forgot to plug in the testing code.

Comment: @remyabel I am using the Visual Studio 2012 editor but told it to use the Visual Studio 2010 (v100) Platform Toolset (for compatibility reasons)

Comment: No, I was referring to things like `Base::value;`, which aren't allowed in standard C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ref#1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10854354/private-conversion-function-results-in-ambiguous-default-type-conversion-error?rq=1) and [ref#2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8455986/using-class-types-in-switch) (I can't seem to find the standard actually saying this, only people quoting it...)

It appears the C++ standard has this to say about conditions:

> The condition shall be of integral type, enumeration type, or of a class type for which a single non-explicit conversion function to integral or enumeration type exists (12.3). If the condition is of class type, the condition is converted by calling that conversion function, and the result of the conversion is used in place of the original condition for the remainder of this section. Integral promotions are performed.

Since there are 2 user-defined-conversions 'available', even though only 1 is accessible the standard says that's not okay.

Answer (score -1):

(What are these `using` statements in `Enum`?  I don't know what they do.)

I'm not sure why the error is happening, but you can certainly solve the problem with the `if` statement by adding something like this to `Base`:

```
inline operator bool () const { return e_ != 0; }
```

As for the `switch`, I've never seen anything but integral types allowed (which `Foo` is not), and I doubt the compiler is smart enough to try to find the cast-to-enum operator on its own.  I would always call `value()` there anyway.